# How to divide a tuple into two in pythonic way

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, list-comprehension

I got a problem which is: receive a tuple with objects of any type, and separate it into two tuples: the first, with strings only; the second, with numbers only.

Alright. The standard algorithm would be something like:

```
def separate(input_tuple):
    return_tuple = ([],[])
    for value in input_tuple:
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return_tuple[0].append(value)
        if isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
            return_tuple[1].append(value)
    return tuple([tuple(l) for l in return_tuple])
```

That way, we only iterate **once**.

My question is: is there a way to do it in a more pythonic way? A one-liner?

I have tried

```
( tuple([i for i in input_tuple if isinstance(i,str)]), tuple([i for i in input_tuple if isinstance(i,numbers.Number)]))
```

But it is less efficient, as we iterate over the input tuple twice.

Also,

```
tuple([ tuple( [i for i in input_tuple if isinstance(i, k)]) for k in ((float ,int,complex), str) ])
```

Has the same problem, as we do two iterations.
Would that be possible to iterate only once and still get the result, or because i am dealing with separation into two tuples, it isn't possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't go for the "pythonic way", it's a pitfall that serves no good and almost always reduces a rather readable and easy to understand piece of code into a 1-line-decoder-ring-requiring mess. Your aim should be to have code formatted into a format that is easy to maintain and read, not to have as few lines as possible.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I am aware of that. I am not actually using that code, but I feel limited when thinking about list comprehension, and I've been studying that lately; people from stack overflow always impress me with their answers, so thats why I am wondering if that is possible! But thanks for the advice! After all, 'Explicit is better than implicit' !

Comment: In Java, we fondly call this process spliteration! spliterators ftw.

Comment: While "pythonic" is somewhat in the eye of the beholder, I would think doing two separate list comprehensions is readable, maintainable and doesn't affect algorithmic complexity, so is actually quite pythonic.  And the results can often surprise you speed-wise, so I recommend timing it.

Comment: Why do so many people seem to think "Pythonic" means "as clever as possible" or "as short as possible"? Readability is probably the single most important quality when judging how Pythonic something is. If you've made your code less readable, then you've also made it less Pythonic. Yes, opinions differ on what's "readable". But readability is definitely a goal baked into the Pythonic ideal, whereas brevity and cleverness are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like

```
my_tuple = ([],[])
for x in a_list:
   my_tuple[isinstance(x,basestring)].append(x)
```

That would make it a little more *pythonic* I guess ... and still pretty readable.

Of course you could also put it in a list comprehension but not a great one:

```
[my_tuple[isinstance(x,basestring)].append(x) for x in a_list]
```

The list comprehension just gets tossed away and its basically being abused into a for loop.

Comment: How would you handle his *"objects of any type"*, though? Your code adds lists, sets, etc into the numbers tuple.

Comment: true this is a very binary solution in which all elements of the list are sorted into one of two bins ... which satisfies my reading of the original problem statement so im just gonna say this simple sorts into strings and non-strings(which may or may not be sufficient)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a one-liner, and it's not even equivalent what you were initially doing, but you could use a container of lists to provide a "mapping" function:

```
>>> from numbers import Number
>>> tup = (1, '2', 3, '4', 5)
>>> di = {}
>>> for x in tup:
...     di.setdefault(Number if isinstance(x, Number) else str if isinstance(x, str) else object, []).append(x)
... 
>>> di[str], di[Number]
(['2', '4'], [1, 3, 5])
```

As @PadraicCunningham has noted in the comments, for Python 2, you can use `basestring` instead of `str` to capture Unicode types.

Comment: This would break as soon as you meet any non int or str

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fixed to make it unbreakable.

Comment: Wow, I Guess this was the most pythonic answer. I would never have thought of that either! Thanks for the answer @Shashank

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, the key function could be arbitrarily complex...for example you could potentially handle multiple types by mapping the values of isinstance to numbers and stuff like that.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Now it handles subclasses of Number and str properly, and items that aren't subclasses of either will get ignored.

Comment: Already have my plus 1 but you should use basestring for Python 2.

Comment: @RafaelCardoso This is starting to look suspciously like a compressed version of your code :P But just note that with a dictionary, you open the door to a lot more interesting keys.

Comment: Sure @Shashank. The positive point is that with the dict it would work for any type - even with user custom classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
tuple(list(filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, t), input_tuple)) for t in (str,int))
```

Comment: very clever .... unfortunately it is still iterating twice :) but that is a cool answer i think (+1)

Comment: Really nice alternative! However as Joran said, it loops twice as my codes did!

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.